# Mock Request and Response of Web service method with Moq Framework

Tags: c#, soap, request, response, moq

**Summary:** I want to be able to mock the request and the response of a SOAP web method which makes calls to a remote server. I want to be able to test the entire request and response functionality of this SOAP web method CustomerCareResult, without having to make the remote server calls. Which means I will have to use **mocking**. I would to like to mock the incoming request and the response output of CustomerCareResult, using Moq Framework in C#.NET. I am COMPLETELY new to writing mock tests in C#, and it has been extremely frustrating for me to figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**NOTE:** There is some psuedocode in here, as the overall code is quite complex, and I just want to give a **general** idea of what it's doing, without adding unnecessary details.

I have a C#.NET class containing a SOAP WebMethod, and 2 other methods, like so:

```
public class TransactionService : System.Web.Services.WebService, 
TransactionServiceNS.ITransactionServiceSoap
{
    //This is a SOAP webservice method
    [WebMethod()]
    public CustomerPutResponse CustomerCareResult(CustomerRequest request)
    {
         //The incoming request parameter of type 'CustomerRequest' 
         //contains the fields: Name, Address, City, State, and AccountNumber
         
         //Call the ApiCreateRequestObj method, passing in the request parameter. This makes 
         //a call to a remote server:
         var apiRequestObj = ApiCreateRequestObj(request);

         //Call the ApiCreateResponseObj method, passing in apiRequestObj, this makes
         //a call to a remote server:
         var apiResponseObj = ApiCreateResponseObj(apiRequestObj );
         return apiResponseObj;
    }

    private CustomerPutRequest ApiCreateRequestObj(CustomerRequest req)
    {
        // PSEUDOCODE:
        //Makes a remote server call, does some processing on the 
       //CustomerRequest req parameter, and returns a "CustomerPutRequest" 
      //object containing all the fields of the req object
        
        //So after processing:
        return new CustomerPutRequest{Name = _req.Name, Address = _req.Address,
        City = _req.City, State = _req.State}
    }

    private CustomerPutResponse ApiCreateResponseObj(CustomerPutRequest cpReq)
    {
        // PSEUDOCODE:
        //Makes a remote server call, does some processing on the cpReq object and returns a 
        //"CustomerPutResponse" object containing the response data
        

        //So after processing:
        return new CustomerPutResponse{/*contains response data fields*/}
    }
}
```

As you see, the SOAP web method CustomerCareResult takes in a "CustomerRequest" parameter, then it calls a method which makes a remote database call, ApiCreateRequestObject(). This does some processing and returns a "CustomerPutRequest" object, which contains the fields of the CustomerRequest object that was passed in.

I then pass this CustomerPutRequest object to ApiCreateResponseObject() method, which in turn makes a remote server call, does some processing of its own, then returns a "CustomerPutResponse" object containing response data, which is returned by the web method CustomerCareResult.

I would to like to mock the incoming request and the response output of the web method CustomerCareResult, using Moq Framework in C#.NET. I am COMPLETELY new to writing mock tests in C#, and it has been extremely frustrating for me to figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might not *have* to use mocking - you can write a ‘fake’ implementation of the web service and use that for your tests - https://tyrrrz.me/blog/fakes-over-mocks

Answer (score 0):

In order to test the class TransactionService without making real calls to the external services, make sure that the services you are using in your pseudocalls are behind an interface. If that's not the case, you may need to refactor your source code to make it testable.

```
public class TransactionService
{
    private readonly IDatabaseService _databaseService;

    public TransactionService(IDatabaseService databaseService)
    {
        _databaseService = databaseService;
    }

    public CustomerPutResponse CustomerCareResult(CustomerRequest request)
    {
        var apiRequestObj = ApiCreateRequestObj(request);

        var apiResponseObj = ApiCreateResponseObj(apiRequestObj);
        
        return apiResponseObj;
    }

    private CustomerPutRequest ApiCreateRequestObj(CustomerRequest req)
    {
        return _databaseService.createPutRequest(req);
    }

    private CustomerPutResponse ApiCreateResponseObj(CustomerPutRequest resp)
    {
        return _databaseService.createPutResponse(resp);
    }
}
```

If you want to test the logic inside TransactionService, not the logic inside the external DatabaseService, you should work with IDatabaseService from TransactionService, and mock the interface IDatabaseService from your tests. The real implementation DatabaseService is only going to run in your application, but your tests won't go through it:

```
public interface IDatabaseService
{
    public CustomerPutRequest createPutRequest(CustomerRequest request);

    public CustomerPutResponse createPutResponse(CustomerPutRequest putRequest); 
}

public class DatabaseService : IDatabaseService
{
    public CustomerPutRequest createPutRequest(CustomerRequest request)
    {
        //PSEUDOCODE: Real code for your real service that returns a customerPutRequest
    }

    public CustomerPutResponse createPutResponse(CustomerPutRequest putRequest)
    {
        //PSEUDOCODE: Real code for your real service that returns a customerPutResponse
    }
}
```

Finally, in your test class (in this example with xUnit) you should test the public methods of your class, in this case the method CustomerCareResult:

```
public class TransactionServiceTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void CustomerCareResult_UponCalled_ReturnsExpectedResponse()
    {
        // Arrange (instantiate input parameters, mocks and the object to test (sut))
        var customerRequest = new CustomerRequest
        {
            Name = "Joe Biden",
            Address = "White House",
            City = "Washington DC",
            State = "Columbia",
            AccountNumber = "666"
        };

        //Create the mock for the external service we don't really want to call
        var dataServiceMock = new Mock<IDatabaseService>();

        //Set up the mock to behave as we would expect the real class to behave when calling its methods.
        //In this case, to return the expected value whenever the external IDatabaseService.createPutRequest is called
        dataServiceMock .Setup(m => m.createPutRequest(It.IsAny<CustomerRequest>()))
                        .Returns(new CustomerPutRequest
                        {
                            Name = "Joe Biden",
                            Address = "White House",
                            City = "Washington DC",
                            State = "Columbia"
                        });

        dataServiceMock.Setup(m => m.createPutResponse(It.IsAny<CustomerPutRequest>()))
                        .Returns(new CustomerPutResponse
                        {
                            Data = "this is the mocked data I expect my real external service to return"
                        });

        var sut = new TransactionService(dataServiceMock.Object);

        // Act (call a method on the sut)
        sut.CustomerCareResult(customerRequest);

        // Assert (verify that each of the 2 the methods in the IDatabaseService mock have been called exactly once)
        dataServiceMock.Verify(m => m.createPutRequest(It.IsAny<CustomerRequest>()), Times.Once());
        dataServiceMock.Verify(m => m.createPutResponse(It.IsAny<CustomerPutRequest>()), Times.Once());
    }
}
```

In the test method, 2 mocks are created with Moq for the service IDatabaseService. In the Setup part, we are telling Moq how we want the mock to respond when TransactionService makes calls to _databaseService.createPutRequest(req) and _databaseService.createPutResponse(resp) under the hood as a result of calling the public method CustomerCareResult.

In the last part of the test, we assert that each method has been called once. Of course, if you have more complex logic inside CustomerCareResult, depending on the information of your request, you might write more tests with different assertions for the same method CustomerCareResult.

Comment: @Rocker2982 I have uploaded a solution wih my example code to GitHub in case you want to take a look to it: https://github.com/jarmanso7/TestAClassWithMoqExample

Answer (score 0):

This might depend on how you make the remote server call. For instance one of my project I used `HttpClient` - it doesn't come with interface (Usually you mock interfaces instead of actual implementations), so I further abstracted it into an `IHttpClientService` which provides `.Get()`, `.Post()` etc., and then implement that using `HttpClient` underneath. I then mock the `IHttpClientService` I created.

[image: How to mock test]

So in your question, `TransactionService` is your test scope, and the actual code depends on something that can make requests towards external service (Which is omitted in your code example). That is what you want to mock.

Of course, point 3 might indicate another issue: one usually shouldn't change the code for the sake of unit testing. But in this case, providing an abstraction of `HttpClient` can help making HTTP requests easier, and because it's kinda historical itself, HttpClient's implementation blocks unit testing, so after considering I figured an abstraction for making HTTP requests was acceptable for my project then.